# Fixing 'System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection' does not contain a definition for 'EnableDefaultBundles' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This error began to appear after update to the latest version of Optimization of System.Web.Optimization.

> 'System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'EnableDefaultBundles'

This also applies for `BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you get the latest `Microsoft Asp.Net Web Optimization Framework` via the NuGet.

Verify that you have `BundleConfig.cs` placed in the `App_Start` folder and also verify that the `BundleConfig.cs` has its Namespace set to the application root Namespace like: `namespace MeApp`

In the Global.asax use  `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI the nuget library name is Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization. Command is Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have System.Web.Optimization then you can install it from the nuget package manager.
Goto **Tools-->nuget package manager--> Package manager console** 
and type the following command. `install-package  Web.Optimization` or if you have already installed and it is creating problem , you can just update the package by the following command `update-package  Web.Optimization`