# cannot get option EnableDefaultBundles() in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying the new bundling feature in asp.net mvc4 razor.

i used

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/framework/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and i am getting output as    -script src="/Scripts/framework/js" > -script-, which returns 404 not found

I looked over some forums suggesting to put

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

in the global.asax file, but i am not getting EnableDefaultBundles() in the option list. 
Is there a certain version requirement ? i have installed .net 4.5

Comment: Have you seen this SO thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279815/fixing-system-web-optimization-bundlecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition

Comment: i did. but still no luck. its not loading those scripts.

Comment: What options do you have when you see intellisense for BundleTable.Bundles. ?

Answer (score 0):

> EnableDefaultBundles has been deprecated and will be removed for RTM.

see [Web Optimization in Visual Studio 2012 RC](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/06/04/web-optimization-in-visual-studio-2012-rc/)